# Compare displayed ids with received ids in data set

Tags: jquery, json

Here is the problem,

I get a set of data and need to compare it with the data that has already been displayed (elements have ids)..

Now the displayed data ids need to be compared with the ids in the data and if there are not in the dataset they need to be removed..

i.e.

```
<div id="a1"></div>
<div id="a2"></div>
<div id="a3"></div>
<div id="a4"></div>
```

Data:

```
id:a1
id:a2
id:a4
id:a5
```

So id a3 is not in the data and needs to be removed..

Is there any way to easily compare the displayed ids with those in the data set received.. using jquery?

Comment: you can easily do this using `$('#a3').remove();` just loop through all divs or json and compare it with each other if not found then remove

Comment: that is what i know... but the question is how to do it in code..

basically i need some example of this..

Answer (score 0):

Is it like this?

```js
$(function(){
  var data = ["a1","a2","a4","a5"],
      total = 5;
  for(var i=0; i<total; i++) {
    if (data.indexOf("a"+i) < 0)
      $('#a'+i).remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1">a1</div>
<div id="a2">a2</div>
<div id="a3">a3</div>
<div id="a4">a4</div>
<div id="a5">a5</div>
```